# Xvfb error on windows when using watir with headless

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, xvfb

I am trying to use headless with watir on windows 7.

```
env.rb

if ENV['HEADLESS']
  headless = Headless.new
  headless.start
  at_exit do
    headless.destroy
  end
end
```

When I run a test I am getting following error

```
$ cucumber --profile bat
*** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (http://adoxa.110mb.com/ansicon) to get coloured output on Windows
Using the bat profile...
No such file or directory - which Xvfb (Errno::ENOENT)
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/headless-0.3.1/lib/headless/cli_util.rb:4:in ``'
```

Any Idea on how to fix this ? or this only works on linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headless gem works only on Linux. It does not work on Mac or Windows.

Comment: On Mac OS, that's because the display isn't provided by X but by Quartz (or whatever), right?  Not, as on Windows, because Xvfb doesn't exist.

Comment: In answer to my own comment, I should have said Aqua, not Quartz.  In any case, http://j.mp/167A7mp is a tutorial on setting up to run headless on Mac OS X.  An equivalent setup could be achieved on Windows via cygwin, probably.